# Python - Count consecutive string but exclude repeated values

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python. I am trying to count consecutive strings:

Example:

The string is equal to st_st= "IJUYIJIJUUIJIJ"

In this case, I want to count "IJ", so I structured my code as follow:

```
def con(st_st) :
a= "IJ"
return st_st.count(a)
```

It's equal to 5. However, I would like to exclude repeated values. When it's repeating, I just want to count it as a single value: E.g IJ(1) IJIJ(1) IJIJ(1)

Thus, instead of 5 it should be 3.

Do you have any idea how this could be achieved with python? Shall I create a list()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) function.

```
>>> st_st= "IJUYIJIJUUIJIJ"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?:IJ)+', st_st)
['IJ', 'IJIJ', 'IJIJ']
>>> len(re.findall(r'(?:IJ)+', st_st))
3
```

`+` repeats the previous token one or more times. So the consecutive `IJ`'s would be considered as a  single match.

Comment: @Alex try `re.findall(r'(?:IJ){1,2}', st_st)`